# Nested loops in R that create new variable names and lags

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to R, but experienced in Stata. To learn R, I am tracking Covid-19 infections. That requires creating seven-day trailing averages, and I do so with the following loop.

```
for (mylag in c(1:7)) { 
      data <- data %>% group_by(state) %>% mutate(!!paste0("deathIncrease", "_", mylag) := lag(deathIncrease, mylag)) %>% ungroup()
}
```

This works, but then I want to run the same code, not just for deaths, but also for cases. So I tried the following.

```
var_list <- c("deathIncrease", "positiveIncrease")
for (var in var_list) {
  for (mylag in c(1:7)) { 
  var <- enquo(var)
  varname <- enquo( paste0(quo_name(var), "_", mylag) )
    data <- data %>% group_by(state) %>% mutate(!!varname := lag(!!var, mylag)) %>% ungroup()
  }
}
```

But that leads to the error `arg must be a symbol`. Any help would be much appreciated. In Stata, loops are simpler. Is there no package that gets R to automatically fill in the looping variables everywhere, like so: `{{ var }}`?

Edit: here is a minimal working example. The first way to create lags works, but only for `var1`. The second nested loop does not.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~group_var, ~var1, ~var2,
  "A", 1, 10,
  "A", 2, 11,
  "A", 3, 12,
  "B", 1, 10,
  "B", 2, 11,
  "B", 3, 12)

for (mylag in c(1:2)) { 
  df <- df %>% group_by(group_var) %>% mutate(!!paste0("var1", "_lag", mylag) := lag(var1, mylag)) %>% ungroup()
}

## Another loop
var_list <- c("var1", "var2")
for (myvar in var_list) {
  for (mylag in c(1:2)) { 
    myvar <- enquo(myvar)
    varname <- enquo( paste0(quo_name(myvar), "_", mylag) )
    data <- data %>% group_by(state) %>% mutate(!!varname := lag(!!myvar, mylag)) %>% ungroup()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello econcoder, its kind of difficult to look at your problem without a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `get()`, like `lag(get(myvar), mylag)`, to point the specific column the string `myvar` is referred to:

```
for(mylag in 1:7){
  
  for(myvar in c('deathIncrease', 'positiveIncrease')){
    
    data <- data %>% 
      group_by(state) %>% 
      mutate(
        !!paste0(myvar, '_', mylag) := lag(get(myvar), mylag)
      ) %>% 
      ungroup() 
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first solution contained a function, that did not respect grouped data. I wanted to look at that anyways, so i spend a bit of time to respect grouped data as well.

This is my solution now, it works as expected on grouped data, but it feels a bit hacky tbh.

```
add_lag <- function(.data, column, days) {
  group <- unlist(groups(.data))
  
  if(is.null(group)){
    new <- mapply(function(x, y) {
      lag(x, y)
    }, x = .data[column], y = sort(rep(days, length(column))))
      
    if(is.null(dim(new))){
      new <- t(new) 
    }  
    new <- as.data.frame(new, stringsAsFactors = F)
  
    names(new) <- paste0(column, "_", sort(rep(days, length(column))))
    new <- as_tibble(new) %>% 
      select(sort(names(new)))
    
    mutate(.data, !!!new)
  } else {
    tmp <- .data %>% 
      nest()

    tmp$data <- lapply(tmp$data, function(x,y){
      x %>% 
        add_lag(column,y)

    }, y = days)
  
    tmp %>% unnest(c(data))    
  }
}


df <- tribble(
  ~group_var, ~var1, ~var2,
  "A", 1, 10,
  "A", 2, 11,
  "A", 3, 12,
  "B", 1, 10,
  "B", 2, 11,
  "B", 3, 12)

df %>% 
  group_by(group_var) %>% 
  add_lag("var1", 1:2)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   group_var [2]
  group_var  var1  var2 var1_1 var1_2
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A             1    10     NA     NA
2 A             2    11      1     NA
3 A             3    12      2      1
4 B             1    10     NA     NA
5 B             2    11      1     NA
6 B             3    12      2      1
```